# How to access preprocess in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp-preprocess

I am working on web application Angularjs with gulp.

Using gulp I am created one environment variable like below

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV  || 'test';

gulp.task('preprocess', function() {
    log('Preprocess..');
    log(env)
    // Minify and copy all JavaScript (except vendor scripts)
    return gulp.src(source.scripts)
        .pipe(preprocess({context:{target:env}}))
});
```

And this is my gulp output

```
[11:23:02] Starting 'preprocess'...
[11:23:02] Preprocess..
[11:23:02] test
[11:23:02] Finished 'preprocess' after 370 ms
```

But I can't access this environment variable inside my angular code. I don't know need to include any plugins are not?

This is my js code for access environment variable

```
//@ifdef  env='test'
    alert('Environment variable test');
//@endif

//@ifdef  env='local'
alert('Environment variable local');
//@endif    

//@ifdef  env='dev'
alert('Environment variable dev');
//@endif
```

How can I access the environment variable created by gulp.

Please help me.

Comment: development !== dev
try changing your @ifdef env='dev' to what your gulp file outputs as the env if that is what you expect.

Comment: your answer is normal javascript, but this is preprocess

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are developing an SPA that serves up index.html.

If so then use a server side HTML templating library to pre-process your HTML. We personally are using jade.

You essentially convert index.html to Jade - giving you index.jade. Create a gulp task to write your Jade to HTML. In the gulp task you can set variables that Jade will use to write the index.html.

In your index.jade do something like ...

```
<html class="VARIABLE_FROM_GULP_TASK"> <!-- this would be written in Jade -->
```

your gulp task would do the HTML conversion

then you can check if the class exists or not inside your JavaScript or in your CSS do something like ...

```
.var_exist .body { color:red }
.var_not_exist .body { color:blue }
```

note that the value of the variable will be written into the HTML file at build time.

Hope that helps.